# Crystal Reports asking for parameter values again

Tags: vb.net, parameters, crystal-reports, parameter-passing

I have a problem in Crystal Reports showing the dialog box asking my `insertquery` values but I have already my values on that parameter. Why still asking even I have values? Can you help me with this?

Code

```
Private Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    If DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, CDate(dtpFrom.Value.ToShortDateString), CDate(dtpTo.Value.ToShortDateString)) < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Date Range", "Invalid Date", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If dgCustomer.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim report_Batch As New BILLINGRBatch
    Dim strName As String = ""
    Dim strSelect As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To dgCustomer.Rows.Count - 1
        If CBool(dgCustomer.Item(0, i).Value) = True Then
            Dim intId As Integer = dgCustomer.Item(1, i).Value
            strName = Replace(Trim(dgCustomer.Item(2, i).Value), "'", "''")

            Dim payFilter As String = ""
            If txtPayId.Text <> 0 Then
                payFilter = " AND a.status = '" & txtPayId.Text & "'"
            End If

            Dim dateFilter As String = ""
            If dtpFrom.Value <> dtpTo.Value Then
                dateFilter = " AND (SELECT start_date FROM bill_transaction1 WHERE transaction_id = a.transaction_id) BETWEEN ''" & dtpFrom.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'' AND ''" & dtpTo.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "''"
            End If
            strSelect = "insert into @t (customerid, customername,payFilter,dateFilter) select '" & intId & "','" & strName & "','" & payFilter & "','" & dateFilter & "' " & Chr(13)
        End If
    Next

    For Each table As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In report_Batch.Database.Tables
        Dim logonInfo As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo
        logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = serverName
        logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = serverDB
        logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = serverUser
        logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = serverPass
        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logonInfo)
    Next

    For Each subReport As ReportDocument In report_Batch.Subreports
        For Each Table As Table In subReport.Database.Tables
            Dim logonInfo As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo = Table.LogOnInfo
            logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = serverName
            logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = serverDB
            logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = serverUser
            logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = serverPass
            Table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logonInfo)
        Next
    Next
    report_Batch.SetParameterValue("insertquery", strSelect) 'this is my insertquery values
    report_Batch.SetParameterValue("customername", strName)


    frm_printing.crp_report.ReportSource = report_Batch
    frm_printing.crp_report.Zoom(100%)
    frm_printing.crp_report.Refresh()
    frm_printing.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Comment: can someone assist me? or anyone encounter this problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the `.Refresh` after you set the parameter values. The report should work as expected if you remove this line from your code:

```
frm_printing.crp_report.Refresh()
```

Comment: I remove my `frm_printing.crp_report.Refresh()` but it still asking the values of my parameter `insertquery`